# How do I pass a Tcl data structure to Perl with Telnet in between?

Tags: perl, serialization, tcl, telnet, expect

I want to telnet into a Cisco router, login and execute a Tcl script that is locally stored in the router's flash. This Tcl script does some processing and should return a nested hash (preferred) or a string that represents a XML document.

Is there a way to map a Tcl nested hash to a Perl nested hash, or to return a string that represents a XML document? Does Expect allow me to do any of the above, and how?

Comment: Expect is a tool for automation of command line utilities; if you have a script already written on the Cisco, you can use expect to log into it and execute it. But you'll have to write the TCL script yourself.

Comment: what i am worrying about is if i can pass the result (nested hash or string) of what the Tcl script does, to a Perl nested hash or a variable holding a string. and the way of doing the latter, of course.

Comment: “Tcl nested hash”? What version of Tcl is in that Cisco box?

Comment: To be clear, the only thing you can communicate between the Tcl code and the Perl code is a string, but that string can be a document in some useful format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expect script should take the file off the router and leave it in /tmp/xferfile.txt. It will need to be modified with the commands that actually produce the file, since I do not have those, I left placeholders for them in the script. You should be able to use Donal's code for that.

It's been a while since I've played with expect and cisco IOS, so bear with me if this needs some debugging on your end.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set prompt1 "Router>"
set prompt2 "Router#"
set prompt3 "bash\$"
set ctrld [expr ("d" & 01xF)]

spawn ssh "$user\@$ip"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";

# switch to privileged EXEC level 
expect $prompt1 { send "enable" }

# ==================================================
# Modify this line for your needs
# ==================================================
expect $prompt2 { send "command to print Tcl hash" }

# Capture output to variable
set results $expect_out(buffer)

# leave EXEC level
expect $prompt2 { send "exit" }
# Command to log out of router
expect $prompt1 { send "exit" }

# Create text file on localhost
spawn "#!/bin/bash"
expect prompt3 { 
    send "cat > /tmp/xferfile.txt"
    sleep 5
    send $results
    send $crtld
    }

expect prompt3 { send "exit" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Serialise the data to a common exchange format, e.g. a JSON string.

Have the Tcl program [emit JSON](http://code.google.com/p/tcl-json/). [Load the JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON%3a%3aAny) from Perl into a hash.

Comment: thanx daxim, there are 2 issues: i don't think that the tcl shell available in a cisco device has yeti installed, but i'll look for it. and second, let's say that we agree on the JSON format, it looks as a good approach, what i am seeking is how to pass the tcl variable (in json format) over a telnet connection or using expect, in the other words using the API of the two modules mentioned above.

Comment: it seems Albert Perrien that you know better than me, so could you please tell me how do i return a tcl nested hash (and not a string using log_user) to perl nested hash in detail (commands, etc.) ?

Comment: There's a JSON generator on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/JSON#Tcl which is pure Tcl code, but it requires 8.6 which I bet won't be on that Cisco router. A more restricted version (without type autodetection) could be built by assembling the bits there.

Comment: My apologies, didn't mean to be snippy there. What version of Tcl do you have on the router, and can you post a sample data structure of what you're trying to pass?

Answer (score 1):

Cisco routers tend to run old versions of Tcl, and to not have a large range of extension packages available. That means that you're quite restricted in what you can do. Luckily, for the job of producing data that can be collected and parsed by Perl, it's actually fairly straight-forward.

Let's use JSON as the interchange format. (Others are possible too.) Daxim's answer tells you how to parse JSON, but that's quite easy because you're running in a context you can control. How to generate JSON data in that crufty old Tcl? The easiest method is with the [`subst`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/subst.htm) command — it's been functionally unchanged in Tcl for ages, so you've definitely got it — and a few helper commands. Here's the outline:

```
proc getFoo {} {
    # Some regular Tcl code to get the value
}
proc getFruit {variety} {
    # Some regular Tcl code to get the value
}
set someIntValue [expr { 1 + 2 * 3 }]    ;#  Or whatever...
set jsonTemplate {
    {
        "foo": [getFoo],
        "bar": {
            "pears":  "[getFruit pears]",
            "apples": "[getFruit apples]"
        },
        "grill": $someIntValue
    }
}
puts [subst $jsonTemplate]
```

OK, caveat time: I've no idea what data you're wanting to receive (“nested hashes” isn't very much to go on). You'll have to add quoting/backslashing where required. Put the procedures *before* the call to `subst` (the order of things matters in Tcl).